# access instance variable defined in ClassMethod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller where I'd like to define a specific list of permissions, like this:

```
class Backoffice::OrdersController < ApiController
  include BackofficeAuthenticator
  before_action :authenticate_agent
  permissions :admin, :tech_god
```

I created this method `permission` on `BackofficeAuthenticator`:

```
module BackofficeAuthenticator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def permissions(*permissions)
      instance_variable_set(:@permissions, permissions)
    end
  end

def authenticate_agent
    raise MissingAccessToken if token.blank?
    @decoded_payload = JWT.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, true, algorithm: 'HS256').first
    if instance_variable_get(:@permissions).present?
      raise NotAllowed if @permissions.include? agent_permissions
    end
  end
```

but when I try to read this variable as above (`instance_variable_get(:@permissions).present?`)  I get `nil`. 
My question is: how can I define the permissions on the controller as I want and access these values on the authenticator module?

**Edit**

I *kinda* get it, as following:

```
module ClassMethods
  def permissions(*permissions)
    instance_variable_set(:@defined_permissions, permissions)
  end
end
```

and

```
def authenticate_agent
    raise MissingAccessToken if token.blank?
    @decoded_payload = JWT.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, true, algorithm: 'HS256').first
    defined_permissions = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@defined_permissions)
```

at this point, `defined_permissions` has the values set before, but I'm not really sure if it is right to do this way.

I also added `base.extend ClassMethods` on the end of `included do |base|`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a *class* instance variable here, for `@permissions` -- so should that not be: `self.class.instance_variable_get(:@permissions)`?

Comment: as I thought! see my edit, wdyt?

Comment: My only other key thought is: Why are you using `instance_variable_set` here? You could have just written: `@permissions = permissions`, no? Other than that, LGTM.

Comment: @TomLord: and then maybe define a reader, so that there's no need for `instance_variable_get` too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev where exactly?

Comment: Why don't use `@@a_class_variable` for class variables?

Comment: @user8018795 e.g. because class variables are shared between the classes hierarchy tree (and have many other drawbacks.)

Comment: @user8018795 You could do... But class variables in ruby have several "strange" behaviours. It's generally advisable to use class *instance* variables instead, which is what has been done above.

Answer (score 1):

```
module BackofficeAuthenticator
  module ClassMethods
    def permissions=(*permissions)
      @permissions = permissions
    end
    def permissions
      @permissions || [] 
    end
  end

  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def authenticate_agent
    raise NotAllowed if self.class.permissions.include?(agent_permissions)
  end
end
```

Comment: Its usage will look ugly, in a target class. Better to use the getter-slash-setter idiom (IMHO)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the above is the getter/setter idiom, isn’t it?

Comment: Nah. I meant one method that does both. Depending on whether you pass it an argument or not

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it’s impossible to empty the permissions with that approach if splatted parameters are allowed.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not a concern at all. Permissions are always set, never changed/emptied. This kind of DSL is quite common.